# A google script for suming two columns from spreadsheet and display back to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a google script to sum two columns of max 50 numbers in a google spreadsheet. however, I cannot get a correct result. The codes are attached below.

```
function DailyCreditCalculation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values_old = sheet.getSheetValues(7,2,50,1);
  var values_new = sheet.getSheetValues(7,3,50,1);
  for(i = 0; i <= values_new.length-1; i++){
    values_old[i] = +values_old[i];
    values_new[i] = +values_new[i];
    values_old[i] = values_old[i] + values_new[i];
  }
  var cell = sheet.getRange(7,2,50,1);
  cell.setValues(values_old);
}
```

When I run the script, it shows error that

> "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]"

How can I modify the script so that it can run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The data you are retrieving are two column Vectors which are represented as arrays of arrays for consistency, e.g.

```
[[1],
 [2],
 [3]]
```

which is why you have to do the `+values_old[i]` conversion.

The output of your loop makes the result an Array as specified in the error message so if you have two identical arrays the result will be e.g. `[2,4,6]`.

`setValues` needs an array of array to write data (`Object[][]`).
Since you want it to be a column vector you can say `values_old[i] = [values_old[i] + values_new[i]];` which will make the result

```
[[2],
 [4],
 [6]]
```

a format `setValues` can work with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However, if I do it as you say,
for [[1], [2], [3]]+[[2], [3], [4]], the result come out will becomes [[12],[23],[34]]

Comment: I think I know how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: you would still need to do the casting you did before